How can I pass a supabase query as a typed argument
I have a function to apply a bunch of "standard filters" to a number of variant queries:
const applyFilters = (query: any, options: BillingTxnOptions)

The use of any works, but I loose all type safety,etc.
I see that this like a PostgrestBuilder or subtype. How can I safely type this.
